# Regex: How to mark multiple points but ignore points embedded in letters?

Tags: node.js, regex, regex-group

I am facing a matching problem...
I am trying to mark the multiple dots in an incorrect mail address so that only the relevant dots appear:

```
mike.smith@yahoo..com 
mike....smith@yahoo.com
```

My approach `(\.(?!(\.\w)))` works correctly for several dots in a row, but still matches the single dot in mike.smith@yahoo.com

Do you have an idea?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `\.(?=\.+\w)`?

Comment: How about [`\.\B` (demo)](https://regex101.com/r/y2s67H/1)

Comment: Glad [it worked for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74287918/regex-how-to-mark-multiple-points-but-ignore-points-embedded-in-letters/74300207#comment131155855_74289396), I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match those dots in an email address assuming there should be at least an @ char present, and using a lookbehind is supported:

Note that this does not validate an email format.

```
\.(?=\.[^@\s]*@)|(?<=@[^\s@]*\.)\.
```

**Explanation**

- `\.` Match a dot
- `(?=\.[^@\s]*@)` Positive lookahead, assert a dot directly to the right and an @ char to the right without crossing whitespace chars
- `|` or
- `(?<=@[^\s@]*\.)` Assert an @ char to the left and a dot directly before matching the dot
- `\.` Match a dot

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7ZvWZy/1)

Answer (score 1):

`\.{2,}` would match two or more consecutive dots.

https://regex101.com/r/In9Qzm/1

Comment: Thx for your answer and your comments. I really appreciate your help!!  \.(?=\.+\w) fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\.(?=\.+\w)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4YZyJW/1).

*Details*:

- `\.` - a dot
- `(?=\.+\w)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with one or more dots and then a word char.

Note that `\.\B` will remove any dot that is either at the end of the string or is followed with a non-word char (i.e. a char other than a letter, digit or underscore).